# ¿Cómo agrupar filas de un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

estoy tratando de agrupar las filas de dataframe que tiene la siguiente estructura[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado con groupby pero me cuenta la cantidad de veces, y no me deja los valores agrupados en la otra columna, necesito una salida asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estuve intentando con esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde orderProductsClean es un dataframe, estuve intentando con otras funciones de groupby pero ninguna me sirvió, estoy trabajando con 3.4M de registros. No se que hacer para dejarlo de la forma que necesito

Comment: Bienvenido Nicolas, Puedes subir tu codigo por favor?? a partir de ahi podremos ayudarte mejor... mientras tanto piedes entrar a [ask]...

Comment: muchas gracias por la recomendación de las preguntas y modifiqué el enunciado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguramente hay mejores formas de hacerlo, pero se me ocurre:

```
orderProductsClean.groupby(['orden_Id'])['producto_id'].apply(','.join)
```

Detalle:

- Agrupamos con `group_by`
- A cada grupo, le aplicamos una función anónima que transforma la lista en una concatenación de cadenas separadas por `,`.

Lo anterior funciona siempre que `product_id` sea una cadena, si fuera numérico, antes, hay que convertir cada valor del grupo:

```
orderProductsClean.groupby(['orden_Id'])['producto_id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(e) for e in x))
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, esto era lo que necesitaba! :)